# Python script for moving directories/files while ignoring certain directories/files using shutil?

Tags: python, shutil

I'm looking to build a python script that moves files/directories from one directory to another while referencing a list that notes the files to be copied over.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
import os, shutil

// Read in origin & destination from secrets.py Readlines() stores each line followed by a '/n' in a list

    f = open('secrets.py', 'r')
    paths = f.readlines()

// Strip out those /n

    srcPath = paths[0].rstrip('\n')
    destPath = paths[1].rstrip('\n')

// Close stream

    f.close()

// Empty destPath

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(destPath, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
        for name in dirs:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))

// Copy & move files into destination path

    for srcDir, dirs, files in os.walk(srcPath):
        destDir = srcDir.replace(srcPath, destPath)
        if not os.path.exists(destDir):
            os.mkdir(destDir)
        for file in files:
            srcFile = os.path.join(srcDir, file)
            destFile = os.path.join(destDir, file)
            if os.path.exists(destFile):
                os.remove(destFile)
            shutil.copy(srcFile, destDir)
```

The secrets.py files contains the src/dest paths.

Currently this transfers all files/directories over. I'd like to read in another file that allows you to specify which files to transfer (rather than making a "ignore" list).

Comment: Have you considered using `tar` or `rsync` to do this? They allow you to specify files containing a list of files to include or exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the file list

```
 f = open('secrets.py', 'r')
 paths = f.readlines()

 f_list = open("filelist.txt", "r")
 file_list = map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n'), f_list.readlines())

 ....
 ....
```

and check before copying

```
    for file in files: 
       if file in file_list# <--- this is the condition you need to add to your code
          srcFile = os.path.join(srcDir, file)
       ....
```

if your file list contains pattern of file names to be copied try using "re" module of python to match your file name.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly for files in my root directory, how can I also select directories to be transfered over?

Comment: Currently all directories are transfered.

Comment: Can you give an example? because if you say you want to copy dir1 and file1 but if file1 exists inside dir2 and if you dont copy/create dir2 the file1 will also be not copied.

Comment: So if you mention a directory to be copied all of its subdirs/files should be copied too? if you say a file to be copied all of its parent folder to be copied too?

Comment: If you mention a directory to be copied, all its subdirectories and their contents should be copied. If you mention a file, that file should only be copied if it's in the src directory.